# Replace \\ found at a particular position in a String in java (not all occurrences) with \\\\

Tags: java, string, unicode, char

I am trying to replace \ with double \ in java. Thing is sometimes the \ belongs to a unicode character (eg:\u00E9) and in this case I don't want to do the escape.
Currently I am stuck at the actual replacement of .  This is just an example that will be a bit refactored :

```
static boolean isUnicodeChar(String string) {
        final String regex = "(?<!\\\\)(\\\\\\\\)*\\\\u[A-Fa-f\\d]{4}";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        return matcher.find();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string = "Muir-Torr \\ \\u00E9 syndrome \\u1234 skd just some \\uabcd arbitrary text \\ s";
        System.out.println("Old String: " + string);

        for (int startPosition = string.indexOf('\\'); startPosition >= 0; startPosition = string.indexOf('\\', startPosition + 1)) {
            int strLength = string.length();
//            int endPosition = startPosition + 5;
            int endPosition = startPosition + 6;
            System.out.println("\\ found at position: " + startPosition);

            if (endPosition <= strLength - 1) {
                String stringToCheck = string.substring(startPosition, endPosition);
                System.out.println("Checking : " + stringToCheck);
                if (!isUnicodeChar(stringToCheck)) {
                  //here I should replace the char that is found at start position with "\\\\"
                    System.out.println("New String: " + string);

                } else {
                    System.out.println("No replacement needed, is unicode char: " + stringToCheck);

                }
            } else {
              //here I should replace the char that is found at start position with "\\\\"
                System.out.println("New String: " + string);
            }
        }

    }
```

Replaced string should be:
`"Muir-Torr \\\\ \\u00E9 syndrome \\u1234 skd just some \\uabcd arbitrary text \\\\ s"`;

Comment: There is no point in specifying `Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE`. Neither of these flags is required by your pattern. Besides that, it’s weird to use regex solely for checking for contradictions, instead of using it to search for the matches in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's just replace all backslashes with 2. The joy of Java escaping...

```
String replaced = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Now we need to tell the regex engine "don't do that if the slash is followed by u and four hexadecimal digits". We can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?!u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})`

```
String replaced = string.replaceAll("\\\\(?!u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Result:

```
Muir-Torr \\ \u00E9 syndrome \u1234 skd just some \uabcd arbitrary text \\ s
```

You can repeat step one to get your desired result.

Comment: Instead of `[0-9a-fA-F]`, you can also use `\p{XDigit}`

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much! Can't believe it is so simple! I was over complicating the solution a lot!